# angularjs and rails 4 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Here is my angular module and route

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/photo', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/photo.html',
        controller: 'PageController'
    })
}])
```

When I run my app getting error as

```
error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
```

I have used this [angularjs gem](https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails)

Can any one help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngRoute` is a separated module since some (maybe 1.2) version of AngularJS.
gem includes all modules, you just have to require needed ones in your `application.js`:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-route
```

Here is the list with all available modules:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-cookies
//= require angular-loader
//= require angular-mocks
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-sanitize
//= require angular-scenario
//= require angular-touch
```